# JavaScript Button to Lightning Component?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, javascript

This is currently an OnClick JS button that I have. Can this be converted into a Lightning Component?

```
​location.replace('/email/author/emailauthor.jsp?retURL=/{!Demo__c.Id}&template_id=00XF0000001UAxV&p3_lkid={!Demo__c.Id}&p24={!Demo__c.BR_Email__c}');
```

Answer (score 1):

Javascript buttons are not supported in lightning because of security concerns.

Salesforce has this [blog](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2016/09/why-its-time-to-break-up-with-javascript-buttons-and-embrace-lightning.html) which provides some alternatives to Javascript buttons in lightning world. This [Trailhead](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/modules/lex_javascript_button_migration) module would help as well.